# How do I INSERT INTO t1 (SELECT * FROM t2) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, how do I populate or update a table from a `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

SQLalchemy doesn't build this construct for you. You can use the query from text.

```
session.execute('INSERT INTO t1 (SELECT * FROM t2)')
```

---

## EDIT:

More than one year later, but now on sqlalchemy 0.6+ [you can create it](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/compiler.html#compiling-sub-elements-of-a-custom-expression-construct):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Executable, ClauseElement

class InsertFromSelect(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, table, select):
        self.table = table
        self.select = select

@compiler.compiles(InsertFromSelect)
def visit_insert_from_select(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "INSERT INTO %s (%s)" % (
        compiler.process(element.table, asfrom=True),
        compiler.process(element.select)
    )

insert = InsertFromSelect(t1, select([t1]).where(t1.c.x>5))
print insert
```

Produces:

```
"INSERT INTO mytable (SELECT mytable.x, mytable.y, mytable.z FROM mytable WHERE mytable.x > :x_1)"
```

---

## Another EDIT:

Now, 4 years later, the syntax is incorporated in SQLAlchemy 0.9, and backported to 0.8.3; You can create any `select()` and then use the new `from_select()` method of `Insert` objects:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column
>>> t1 = table('t1', column('a'), column('b'))
>>> t2 = table('t2', column('x'), column('y'))
>>> print(t1.insert().from_select(['a', 'b'], t2.select().where(t2.c.y == 5)))
INSERT INTO t1 (a, b) SELECT t2.x, t2.y
FROM t2
WHERE t2.y = :y_1
```

[More information in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_09.html#insert-from-select).

Comment: Would you suggest session.execute('INSERT INTO t1 (%s)' % str(sqlalchemy_select_expression))?

Comment: Sure, why not - don't need the `str()` though, since `%s` already does that.

Comment: @hadrien: now you have http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/compiler.html#compiling-sub-elements-of-a-custom-expression-construct where you could compile it.

Comment: I love that you've updated this over time, but it'd be nice if this were broken into latest to oldest, with the sqlalchemy version called out instead of the years between edits ;)

Comment: And if you don't want to `select *` but rather `select x, y` only (out of many columns), one way is to `from sqlalchemy import select` and then you can use this one like `select([t2,x, t2,y])` instead of `t2.select()`.

Comment: @nosklo I have a doubt regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266107/sqlalchemy-relationships-row-in-child-table-is-dependent-on-two-parent-tables. Would you mind answering it?

Answer (score 34):

As of 0.8.3, you can now do this directly in sqlalchemy: [Insert.from_select](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html?highlight=from_select#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.from_select):

```
sel = select([table1.c.a, table1.c.b]).where(table1.c.c > 5)
ins = table2.insert().from_select(['a', 'b'], sel)
```

Comment: How about scopped session?

Comment: Do I need to import insert()?
If yes, how do I import ?
I get `AttributeError: type object 'table2' has no attribute 'insert'`

Comment: @VamshiPulluri it sounds like your `table2` is a class, not a table object for SQL expressions. See `nosklo`'s answer below on constructing table objects (under *Another EDIT*) or follow the SQLAlchemy tutorial here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#define-and-create-tables

Answer (score 1):

As Noslko pointed out in comment, you can now get rid of raw sql:
http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/compiler.html#compiling-sub-elements-of-a-custom-expression-construct

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Executable, ClauseElement

class InsertFromSelect(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, table, select):
        self.table = table
        self.select = select

@compiles(InsertFromSelect)
def visit_insert_from_select(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "INSERT INTO %s (%s)" % (
        compiler.process(element.table, asfrom=True),
        compiler.process(element.select)
    )

insert = InsertFromSelect(t1, select([t1]).where(t1.c.x>5))
print insert
```

Produces:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (SELECT mytable.x, mytable.y, mytable.z FROM mytable WHERE mytable.x > :x_1)
```

Comment: Now you don't have to create your own ClauseElement. You can use the new `Insert.from_select` method! See my answer.