# How to insert in sqlalchemy from a select, specifying columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

This question is related to the following question:

[How do I INSERT INTO t1 (SELECT * FROM t2) in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849375/how-do-i-insert-into-t1-select-from-t2-in-sqlalchemy)

but I'd like to specify which columns the insert should work on. That is, I'd like sqlalchemy to generate a query equivalent to

`INSERT INTO t1 (col1, col2, col3) SELECT x,y,z FROM t2`

I looked at the compilation documentation, but it's not clear to me how to modify the [example](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/compiler.html#compiling-sub-elements-of-a-custom-expression-construct) to be able to specify the column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following modifications might help:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Executable, ClauseElement

class InsertFromSelect(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, table, columns, select):
        self.table = table
        self.columns = columns
        self.select = select

@compiles(InsertFromSelect)
def visit_insert_from_select(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "INSERT INTO %s (%s) %s" % (
        compiler.process(element.table, asfrom=True),
        ", ".join(element.columns), # @note: not a very safe/robust way to compose SQL
        compiler.process(element.select)
    )

insert = InsertFromSelect(
        t1,
        ("col1", "col2", "col3",),
        select([t2.c.x, t2.c.y, t2.c.z])
        )
print insert
```